# What happen if I uninstall macOS sierra installer?

Tags: mac, macos, disk-space

Can you tell me what happens if I delete the macOS Sierra installer which take nearly 5 gigabytes on my Mac?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safe to delete, you will just be unable to install macOS Sierra until you re-download the installer from the Mac AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing at all except you would have to download it again if you ever need it.

After install, the file would usually be deleted anyway, unless you move it to another location.

Comment: Thanx a lot, I have just removed the installer, and indeed nothing happened :) I will mark your answer as approuved as soon as the 6min I have to wait will be finished.